# DAX to get previous time period, no matter if sliced by week, month, year, fiscal month, day, etc

Tags: powerbi, ssas, dax, ssas-tabular

I have created a date table in a Power BI data model that includes Date, Week, Month, Year, Fiscal Month, etc.

If I am sliced by week (the week appearing in the "Columns" section of a Power BI Matrix Visual), then I am including 7 rows of data (one for each day) from the date table.  If by month, then it could be anywhere from 28 to 31 days.

I'm creating a measure that depends on calculating values for the previous slice's date range.  For instance, if I am sliced to 6/15/2020 then I need to make a calculation for 6/14/2020 and if I'm sliced by Month then I need the previous month's date range, etc.

Is there a way in DAX to slice by the previous slice or to detect which field you are currently sliced by?

I would like to avoid writing a giant `if` statement to detect the different possibilities.  I am hoping there is a generic way to retrieve all the dates in the previous slice no matter how we are sliced.

I have made use of the typical `parrallelperiod`, `datesinperiod`, `datesmtd`, etc. but that is not what I'm looking for.

Date tables typically have several hierarchies that could allow for use of stuff like `isinscope`, but since I don't want to have a giant block of code to run through the various things that could potentially be in scope, I don't think that approach will work either.

My goal is to build a single measure that would work for users building various reports no matter which date field they slice by.

Answer (score 0):

Since Week isn't even a period that Time Intelligence works for (as fas as I understand), I don't think there's much hope for a clean general solution but here are a couple of imperfect approaches sketched:

#### 1. SWITCH

```
PriorSlice =
VAR PriorDates =
    SWITCH (
        TRUE (),
        ISFILTERED ( DateTable[DateKey] ), DATEADD ( DateTime[DateKey], -1, DAY ),
        ISFILTERED ( DateTable[Week] ), DATEADD ( DateTime[DateKey], -7, DAY ),
        ISFILTERED ( DateTable[Month] ), PARALLELPERIOD ( DateTime[DateKey], -1, MONTH ),
        ISFILTERED ( DateTable[Year] ), PARALLELPERIOD ( DateTime[DateKey], -1, YEAR )
    )
RETURN
    CALCULATE ( [Measure], PriorDates )
```

(I'm not sure if `ISINSCOPE` would be better than `ISFILTERED` here or not.)

#### 2. Shift by days in scope

```
PriorSlice =
VAR Shift = 1 + MAX ( DateTable[DateKey] ) - MIN ( DateTable[DateKey] )
RETURN
    CALCULATE ( [Measure], DATEADD ( DateTable[DateKey], -Shift, DAY ) )
```

This won't really work for uneven periods like months. For example, you have February selected and want to get all of January (instead of the last 28/29 days).

---

Ultimately, you're going to need some kind of `SWITCH` either in your measure or in a helper measure if you want to work at multiple time granularities simultaneously.

Comment: Thank you for those suggestions. #1 is the "giant if" statement I am hoping to avoid, but I'm afraid that is probably what I will have to do.  #2 is, as you pointed out, going to be inaccurate in some cases.